# Inequality for two complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

If $a,b$ are any two complex numbers, then
$$2(|a|^2+|b|^2)= |a+b|^2+|a-b|^2$$ and therefore
$$2(|a|^2+|b|^2)\geq |a+b|^2.$$ My curiosity; Is there any genarization of the above inequality like

$$c(|a|^p+|b|^p)\geq |a+b|^p$$ where $c=f(p)>0$ and $p>1?$

Answer (score 3):

Just the real number version would suffice, since $\lvert a\rvert+\lvert b\rvert\geq\lvert a+b\rvert$ gives $(\lvert a\rvert+\lvert b\rvert)^p\geq\lvert a+b\rvert^p$.  So any $c=f(p)\geq\inf_{x\in[0,1]} ((1-x)^p+x^p)^{-1}$ would do.

Comment: It appears $c=2^{p-1}$ looks fine!

Comment: We know that $|a|^p+|b|^p>(|a|+|b|)^p,$ for $0<p<1.$ Can this also be bettered with an appropriate $c=f(p)?$